# Rails TurboStream sync polymorphic views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

iam working on a task that make appointments that will show on calendar in which the appointment's position be calculated by its `start_time` and `end_time`, iam using Rails7 + TurboStream to sync (real time) the appointment(create/update/destroy) between its participants.

Here is the problem: participants (users) live in different `timezones` so that the position of the appointment on each user's calendar are different, for example, i setup a appointment at my timezone at 8AM->10AM, my partner will see the appointment on 8PM->10PM due to his timezone. Now if the appointment data in `json` format then which some code in `js` (on frontend) we could handle this case. But how could we do it by server rendering effectively ? Hotwire style will sync HTML directly to clients, hence i have to broadcast the appointment's html in variant timezones to all participants.

```rb
  # appointment view on calendar
  <div id="appointment<%= appointment.id %><%= current_user.timezone %>"
       class="absolute top- left-" # <-- base on timezone

  # update appointment success -> sync
  def update
    # ...
    if @appointment.save
      # ....
      @appointment.participant_timezones.each do |tz|
        Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_replace_to(
          @appointment,
          target: ...,
          partial: ..., # this will be render base on user timezone       
          locals: {timezone: tz}
        )
      end
  end
```

As you can see, in my current solution, i have to sync multiple turbo frames (for each participant's timezone) and i also need to sync/cache timezones, i think it is not an effective way.

Is there any way to intercept `turbo js` so that i just broadcast only one turbo frame and each client js will manipulate it before do Dom actions ?

```rb
                                                    -> user1: turbo.js update css position -> dom replace
                                                    |
one update appointment -> broadcast updated frame ->|->user2:  ................................
                                                    |
                                                    -> ...
```

Comment: Typically the solution to this problem is to just have the server deal with UTC and output global times. For example `<time datetime"2011-11-18T14:54:39.929Z">2:54 PM</time>`. That lets you cache the response and avoid the complexity on the server side. The client side is then responsible for replacing the text with a localized respresentation. Not completely sure how to apply this approach to turboframes though.

Comment: thanks @max, i actually did it, from services to db, time always in UTC time zone, from controllers , presenters and views time in user current time zone. Today i came up with a cheating way that server side will always render with UTC time zone but the view is `hidden` and stick to a stimulus controller which will manipulate the view before remove css `hidden` and show the view at the position it should be show, however it only work for `create/destroy` since the dom actions always be executed before that so i still stuck in case `update`.